# How to set canvas height and width to file api image height and width?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

Basically I have a file api and a canvas, What I want is to set the height and width of my canvas to chosen image from file api.

So far I could is to go this far:

```
reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function(e){
    showUploadedItem(e.target.result, file.fileName);
}
reader.readAsDataURL(file);

var sendingcontext = sendingcanvas.getContext('2d');
var imagetosend = new Image();
imagetosend.onload = function(){
    sendingcanvas.width=imagetosend.width;
    sendingcanvas.height=imagetosend.height;
sendingcontext.drawImage(imagetosend, 0,0);
}
imagetosend.src=window.URL.createObjectURL(input.files[0]);
```

And

```
<div class="div" id="div">
    <canvas id="canvas" class="canvas" width="100" height="100">Your browser does not support out technologies</canvas>
</div>
```

FYI: file height and width is random not just 100 to 100

The problem here is that i only take a part of the image not the actual full image

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: shouldn't it be `sendingcanvas.width` instead of `canvas.width`?

Comment: Okay I missed that one, but now when I changed my imagetosend is empty

Comment: empty in the sense? null? Also on an unrelated note, https://github.com/jayankaghosh/chobi/, this is a library designed to make such things easier. Consider going through it

Comment: Thanks a lot for the library, although I will go through it's docs, but till then could you tell me how to properly resize canvas width and height to auto or to image size, just for next If somehow I faced the same problem again?

Comment: It can't be auto. `sendingcanvas.width=imagetosend.width;` and `sendingcanvas.height=imagetosend.height;` are correct. Try  `sendingcanvas.width=this.width;` and `sendingcanvas.height=this.height;`